# passing an array through the function

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays

My website is featuring online classified advertisements, programmed by PHP and MySQL. The following code let the administrator delete multiple records using the checkbox tool.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >   
  <table>
    <td><? echo $rows['CountryName']; ?></td>
    <td><input name="delete_items[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" /></td>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="deleteSelected" value="Submit" >
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['deleteSelected'])) {
$delete_items = join(', ', $_POST["delete_items"]);  
$query = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN ($deleted_items)";    
$result = mysql_query($query);    
header("Location: admin.php"); }
?>
```

When I press the submit button without checking boxes (all boxes are unchecked), I receive the following error message (p.s. the script is working well without any error message, if any Checkbox being checked):

Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_listing.php on line 87

I’ve tried the `implode` function instead of using `join`, but still I'm getting an error message.
Maybe I do not passing an array through the function correctly, but I cannot find a solution for the above.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe your $_POST["delete_items"] isn't coming through so the join function can't get its second argument properly. Otherwise, try using double quotes for instead of ', '

Comment: @FaddishWorm I also think that $_POST["delete_items"] isn't coming through and that the join function can't get its second argument properly, but how can I get it solved? Thanks.

Comment: please show us the output of: `var_dump($_POST['deleteSelected']);`

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are displaying *all* the records from your database into a single input in the form.

The code will probably work well with the `implode()` as you tried, but you will need to use a loop in the displaying of the form to generate it properly with the options.

Something like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >   
    <table>
    <?php
    while($row=$databaseResult) //however you are getting the data out of the database.
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$rows['CountryName']."</td><td><input name='delete_items[]' type='checkbox' value=".$rows['id']."/></td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="deleteSelected" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying to help, I found a simple solution by adding one code line, as follows:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['deleteSelected'])) { 
  if(isset($_POST["delete_items"][0])) {
    $delete_items = join(', ', $_POST["delete_items"]);   
    $query = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN ($delete_items)";     
    $result = mysql_query($query);     
    header("Location: admin.php"); 
  }
 } 
?>
```

Hope it can help someone else...